# webview in core animation layer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, calayer

I wanted to create a webView inside of a CALayer. Maybe it is too trivial but I am just getting my head into CA. Would anyone please be able to help?

cheers
Ron

Answer (score 2):

Views can contain layers, Views can contain other views, and layers can contain layers. But layers cannot contain views.

If you want to animate a `WebView`, your best bet would be to embed it in an `NSView` where you've called `setWantsLayer:YES` and then animating the `WebView`'s layer.

Comment: WebView's don't support being layer-backed, so -setWantsLayer: is not a good idea. Your only supported way to get animations in a WebView at present is to use CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works because webview doesn't seem to like core animation enabled in any view containing it.   I'd simply like to get a drop shadow or blur effect on the screen behind my webview and I've tried enabling it in the parent or even in a view behind the webview... but nothing seems to work.  I may be doing something wrong though.