# Sliding from One View to Another

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, core-graphics

How would I change from one view to another with a slide transition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place them side by side, and use [NSViewAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSViewAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to perform the animation.

This may turn out tricky if the views' size can change. Doubly so if the two views are not the same size as each other.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't do it like you said (side by side), instead I found this article with another easy way to do it. http://bish.fr/5vyr.

Answer (score 1):

Marcus Zarra gives a good example of how to use Core Animation to achieve this effect in his [post on how to implement a wizard](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/03/core-animation-tutorial-wizard-dialog-with-transitions/).  It's very simple to do using subviews and a CATransition.

Comment: That's a good example and almost works except in the second view everything doesn't work. In the second view I have a web view and it is completely blank even though I know content is there. Here is a video showing it  … http://fwdr.org/z9tf.

Comment: Unfortunately, WebViews can't be layer-backed on the Mac, so they won't play nice with Core Animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618498/webview-in-core-animation-layer .  If that's your case, I'd follow Peter's suggestion of using NSViewAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

Implement all the actual drawing using CALayers. (Having not used Core Animation myself, I can't get more specific.) Put them in a single view, hosting that layer hierarchy, and use Core Animation to perform the slide transition.

This may not work so well if the views are not display-only—that is, if they host controls that the user can interact with. Layers are more or less display-only, since you can't put a view in a layer, and only views, not layers, are responders.